# Passing a function to a variadic function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Consider the following function templates:

```
template<typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
void foo0(std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)> f) {}

template<typename RetType, typename ArgType>
void foo1(std::function<RetType(ArgType)> f) {}
```

And the following function:

```
void bar(int n) {}
```

Why does the following occur:

```
 foo0<void, int>(bar);  // does not compile
 foo1<void, int>(bar);  // compiles fine
```

The compilation error is (gcc-8 with C++17):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo0<void, int>(void (&)(int))'
   foo0<void, int>(bar);
                      ^
note: candidate: 'template<class RetType, class ... ArgTypes> void foo0(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>)'
 void foo0(std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)> f) {}
      ^~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types 'std::function<void(_ArgTypes ...)>' and 'void (*)(int)'
   foo0<void, int>(bar);
```

Using a dummy template

```
template<typename T>
void bar(int n) {}
```

makes `foo0<void, int>(bar<int>);` compile fine in gcc-8 but gives an error using clang with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5).

The clang error is

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo0'
  foo0<void, int>(bar<int>);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (int, type-parameter-0-1...)>' against 'void (*)(int)'
void foo0(std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)> f) {}
```

Comment: Trying to _deduce_ the type of `std::function` is almost always the wrong thing to do. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the following occur [?]

Take in count that when you call

```
 foo0<void, int>(bar); // compilation error
 foo1<void, int>(bar); // compile
```

`foo0()` and `foo1()` are expecting a `std::function` and `bar` is a pointer to a function that can be converted to a `std::function` but isn't a `std::function`.

In the `foo1()` case, you explicit both `RetType` and `ArgType` template parameters, so the compiler can convert `bar` to a `std::function<void(int)>` and all goes well.

But the `foo0()` case is different because the template parameter `ArgTypes...` is a variadic one and calling `foo0<void, int>(bar)` you don't explicit the full `ArgTypes...` variadic list but only the first type.

If I'm not wrong, the problem is that the compiler try to deduce the rest of `ArgTypes...` from the `bar` argument but `bar` isn't a `std::function` so the compiler is unable to deduce the rest of `ArgTypes...`, so the error.

I suppose that

```
foo0<void, int>(std::function<void(int)>{bar});
```

or simply

```
foo0(std::function<void(int)>{bar});
```

or (C++17 only) also

```
foo0(std::function{bar});
```

should compile because, calling `foo0()` this way, the function receive a `std::function` so the compiler can completely deduce the template parameters.

I don't understand how the version with `bar()` with a dummy template parameter

```
foo0<void, int>(bar<int>);
```

can compile with g++-8 and I suppose it's a g++ bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
void foo0(std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)> f) {}
```

the fix is:

```
template<class X>struct tag_t{using type=X;};
template<class X>using block_deduction = typename tag_t<X>::type;

template<typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
void foo0(block_deduction_t<std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)>> f) {}
```

and now your `foo0<void, int>(bar)` compiles.

The general problem is that saying `foo0<void, int>`, you aren't saying "`RetType` is `void` and `ArgTypes...` is `int`.  You are saying `ArgTypes...` **starts with** `int`.

```
std::function<void(int, double)> x;
foo0<void, int>( x )
```

the above compiles fine.

...

Another approach in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) is to add another overload.

Leave this one:

```
template<typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
void foo2(block_deduction_t<std::function<RetType(ArgTypes...)>> f) {}
```

but add:

```
template<typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes, class F>
void foo2(F&& f) {
  return foo2<RetType, ArgTypes...>( std::function{std::forward<F>(f)} );
}
template<int unused, class F>
void foo2(F&& f) {
  return foo2( std::function{std::forward<F>(f)} );
}
```

here we wrap `F` into a construction-guided `std::function`.

Your call to `foo2<int, void>( bar )` now calls `foo2<void, int, decltype(bar)&>`, the 2nd overload.  Then it proceeds to construct a `std::function` from it, and so long as the signatures match exactly it works.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea why my last example compiles using gcc but not using clang?